# Screenshot of Trading View Chart using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, tradingview-api

I'm trying to render a screenshot of a Trading View chart widget on my server, similar to the following :

```
https://jsfiddle.net/exatjd8w/
```

I'm not that familiar with PhantomJS, but tried several ways to take a shot of the chart once it's loaded, the last try using the following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://mywebsite.com/chart', 
    function(status) {

        console.log("Status: " + status);

        if (status === "success") {
            page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
                (page.evaluate(function() {
                  // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
                      console.log('Status: jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM');
                       var date = new Date(),
                           time = date.getTime()
                       $('#main-widget-frame-container iframe').on('load', function() {
                          console.log('iframe loaded, now take snapshot')
                          page.render('screenshot_' + time + '.png')
                       })
                }))
            })
        }
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, still unable to do it right since the above code running forever without results.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is no longer maintained, and has a couple of issues that might cause this.
I'd recommend switching to Puppeteer which has a really nice API, uses Google Chrome (headless) under the hood, and is actively maintained by the chrome team:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Wonderful, works as a expected. Thanks a lot Joseph I've been searching the web and did not find it. I'll start using it instead and find a way to get working with php.

Comment: @NaifAlghamdi Please set it as the accepted answer if it was helpful :)